# Iron Router and this.next()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following route which is working:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  Meteor.call("get_country", function(error, result){

   if(!error){

    if(result === null)
     Session.setDefault("country", "int");
    else{
    if(Countries[result] === null)
      Session.setDefault("country", "int");
    else
      Session.setDefault("country", result);
    }
  Session.setDefault('category', Countries[Session.get("country")]);
  Session.setDefault('sources', Categories[Session.get("country")][Session.get("category")]);
  }
 });
});
```

However in the console, I get

```
Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?
```

I don't use onBeforeAction. 
Should I pay attention to the warning? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to specify a template to load/render:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  Meteor.call("get_country", function(error, result){

   if(!error){

    if(result === null)
     Session.setDefault("country", "int");
    else{
    if(Countries[result] === null)
      Session.setDefault("country", "int");
    else
      Session.setDefault("country", result);
    }
  Session.setDefault('category', Countries[Session.get("country")]);
  Session.setDefault('sources', Categories[Session.get("country")][Session.get("category")]);
  }
  //Specify template to render
  this.render('templateNameForHomeRoute');
 });
});
```

Comment: But if I don't want to render the template with Iron-Router?

Comment: @user2409399 Then I'd suggest putting your method call at the template level:
`Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {Meteor.call(...)}`

Comment: It's also happening for route without method calls. Actually it's happening for an empty route `Router.route('/', function () {});`

Comment: @user2409399 As I said, **you need to specify a template to load/render** `Router.route('/', function () {this.render('templateName')});` I suggest specifying route options instead of a function. (https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-specific-options)